# Arduino and Visual C++ Serial Communication

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, serial-port, arduino, microcontroller

So I found this tutorial for Arduino Visual Studio Communication: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

After reading up on it  I wrote a small program on the Arduino which reads a character's ASCII code and returns that incremented value. I already tested it with the serial monitor. However, when I wrote the program below I not only receive the answer, but I also receive "garbage" as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Serial.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Serial * Arduino = new Serial("COM8");
    cout << "Communicating with COM7 enter data to be sent\n";
    char data[256] = "";
    int nchar = 256;
    char incomingData[256] = "";
    while (Arduino->IsConnected())
    {
        cin >> data;
        Arduino->WriteData(data, nchar);
        Arduino->ReadData(incomingData, nchar);
        cout << incomingData << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The  ouput looks as follows:

```
F:\Serial\Debug>Serial.exe
Communicating with COM7 enter data to be sent
1
2☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
a
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺b☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
^C
F:\Serial\Debug>
```

Can anyone shed light into how I should go about changing this code so that I can send and recieve a specific number of characters or in this case one character. I have already tried changing nchar to 1 so that it would only send a single character; however, this causes the output to display out of sync. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you *always* send `nchar` bytes, no matter how much (or little) you read from the user. And also the data you read from the serial port, you don't terminate it like a string.

For the first it's simple, stop using an array for that, and use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (to avoid possible buffer overflows), and send [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) bytes.

Then when receiving, you need to find out how many bytes you received, and then terminate the array like a string (or use `std::string` there too, there's a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that lets you pass in a pointer and a size).

Comment: Thanks I see what you meant and it helped though I also needed to add a while loop that kept reading until data was available. At least for the first read call.